# CGAL Evaluator: Root node didn't fit into cache can't open file for export

Tags: 3d, command, stl-format, openscad

I need to export Openscad files as .stl files from command line for a CAD program I'm developing. 
I'm testing the command line to ensure the export works. From the program diretory where the openscad program runs on my Windows 8 64bit computer I enter the line:
openscad -o grip.stl grip.scad. grip.scad is in the same directory and I need grip.stl to export to the same directory.

I get a CGAL Evaluator: Root node didn't fit into cache can't open file for export error each time and no file is exported to any where on my computer. Has any one gotten this to run or understands this error.

I have rendering included in the grip.scad file so I know it can render and the file exports from the openSCAD interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on windows vista and windows 7 this works mindless of [documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Using_OpenSCAD_in_a_command_line_environment#Windows_notes):
save your input.scad in an arbitrary directory and cd to this directory.
enter:

```
c:\“program files (x86)“\openscad\openscad.exe -o output.stl input.scad
```

on linux same way, but use:

```
openscad -o output.stl input.scad
```